# What is the most efficient way of converting a std::vector<std::tuple<>> to a torch::Tensor?

Tags: c++, torch, libtorch

I have a vector of tuples that I need to convert into a `torch::Tensor`. What I have come up with so far, is the vanilla approach which is as follows :

```cpp
std::vector<torch::Tensor> anchors;
std::vector<std::tuple<float, float, float, float>> anchors_raw;

//...
for (auto& rows: anchors_raw)
    {
        auto& [cx, cy, s_kx, s_ky] = rows;
        anchors.emplace_back(std::move(torch::stack({ std::move(torch::tensor(cx)),
                                                     std::move(torch::tensor(cy)),
                                                     std::move(torch::tensor(s_kx)),
                                                     std::move(torch::tensor(s_ky))
                                                    }, 0)));
    }
    outo output = std::move(torch::stack(std::move(anchor)).view({ -1,4 }));
    //...
```

I'm using Torch 1.7. Is there any other possibly more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any libtorch feature to do that easily. I would have suggested to use `torch::from_blob`, hoping for the data to be stored contiguously, but I have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597006/stdtuple-memory-alignment) that says otherwise.

So **if possible**, my suggestion would be to replace your `tuple<float, float...>`by `std::array<float, 4>` (for which memory layout is contiguous), and do something like

```
std::vector<std::array<float,4>> anchors_raw;
// ...
auto options = torch::TensorOptions().dtype(at::kFloat);
auto anchors = torch::from_blob(&anchors_raw[0][0], {anchors_raw.size(), 4}, options).clone()
```

I cannot try it at the moment so I hope it compiles and run fine, but I believe it should work, all float values should be stored contiguously in the vector and the arrays, so `from_blob`will work.

As always, the call to `clone` is required if `anchors_raw` is at risk of going out of scope before you're done with `anchors`. If you're sure `anchors_raw` will outlive `anchors`, you can remove the call.

Comment: Thanks a lot really appreciate it as always. This worked just fine, though I had to do some minor changes, like casting the ```anchors_raw.size()``` to ```int```, and also I opted for a ```struct``` instead of the ```std::array```. great job made my life 600x sweeter :-D